# How to hide server info and its applications from the clients

Tags: centos, apache2

Our web server is maintaining several applications: php-fpm and apache tomcat.

We have successfully hidden some of our server information with `ServerTokens Prod` and `ServerSignature Off`, combined with `exposed_php = off`

But after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on), the BuiltWith still be able to know that we're currently use CentOS and Magento as the main application.

Is there any way to hide those information (about the server OS, Magento application, JS frameworks, CSS libraries...) or even change them?

Answer (score 1):

The OS can be fingerprinted remotely, even without a website. What are you trying to achieve by wanting to hide all this information? This will definitely not stop attacks and probing of your public services.

For example, any CMS will generate web pages with some specific content in it (like CSS class names or IDs, etc…). Hence parsing the HTML page that ones get back can give information on its producer, whatever you are doing on an HTTP level with your webserver configuration.

Comment: I mainly want to hide what CMS is used. I know that won't definitely stop attacks but showing all information about the actual application might get more attacks (mostly from crawler tools).